# Adding a custom widget on all pages in Yesod

Tags: yesod

I am building a website with Yesod that contains a search form at the top of every page. From what I have understood till now, I should create a widget for the form, but I am unable to include it in a common place. What is the recommended way to do this?

If I create a custom widget, what is the recommended folder structure to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `defaultLayout` function is intended for: you can add any kind of content to this page, and all pages of your site which use `defaultLayout` will inherit it automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Just a small doubt on that, I have a header.hamlet file and a Header.hs which uses the hamlet file. How should I include the widget in Foundation.

Currently I am using `$(widgetFile "header")`, which I think is not the correct way because then I am not using the Header.hs file.

Comment: If your header.hamlet has all the content you need, then widgetFile should be sufficient. Without knowing what you've put in Header.hs, I can't give you a solid answer, however.

Comment: The Header.hs will contain a search form and some static content such as menu. Search will be handled by a SearchR handler.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to put the code from Header.hs into Foundation.hs, but I still can't be certain.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently when trying to add a header to every page that has a "Login" link if the user is not authenticated, and a "Logout" link if they are. I didn't find any good examples in the documentation of how to do this so I put one together.

*Note: This assumes that you are using the scaffolding, but even if you're not you should still be able to work this in.*

The first thing you need to do is create a header widget and add it to `defaultLayout` in `Foundation.hs`.

```
pageHeaderWidget :: Handler Widget
pageHeaderWidget = do
  mauthId <- maybeAuthId
  return $(widgetFile "header")

defaultLayout widget = do
  pageHeader <- pageHeaderWidget >>= widgetToPageContent
  -- ...
  withUrlRenderer $(hamletFile "template/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```

Then you need to create the corresponding html and style for your header:

File: `header.hamlet`

```
<header>
    $maybe authId <- mauthId
        Welcome #{show aid} - <a href=@{AuthR LogoutR}> Logout
    $nothing
        <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}> Login
```

File: `header.lucius`

```
header {
    background-color: #007fff;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Finally, you need to edit `default-layout-wrapper.hamlet` and add

```
^{pageHead pageHeader}
```

to the `<head>` tag just below `^{pageHead pc}` (generated by the scaffolding); and replace

```
<header>
```

in the `<body>` with

```
^{pageBody pageHeader}
```